# sort one array based on other in ascending order in c

Tags: c, arrays

I want to sort one array in ascending order but values should be checked of other array.

For example:
  I have two arrays diff[] and arr[]
   I want to sort arr[] based on diff[] values. 
Is that possible?

I made changes to simple sorting algo. But it doesn't work out.

Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (diff[i] > diff[j])
            {
                a =  arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Google bubble sort](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort)

Comment: @Lundin but how to sort one array based on other array values?

Comment: provide some example

Comment: What do you mean "based on other array"? What is the relationship between the values in `arr` and `diff`? That is, how does the comparison result of values in `diff` supposed to determine the order of the values in `arr`? Maybe give an example of input array values and output `arr` values.

Comment: Start by writing the correct algorithm, then modify it from there.

Comment: @JerryGoyal may be using values as index for other?

Comment: there may be many interpretations for this. just give a sample input and desired output

Comment: @AlanAu i want to sort an array in ascending order but in doing that values must be compared of other array

Comment: What you have described does not make sense. After you compare the values from the other aray and get a result, how does that result determine the order of the values in the other array (and which values in the other array is it supposed to affect)? Give an example to clear it up.

Comment: @JerryGoyal  arr[]={ 17,14,14,12,11,11,9,5,4,2} diff[]={ 12,9,9,7,6,6,4,0,1,3} sorted arr[]={,5 ,4 ,2 ,9 ,11......}

Comment: @AlanAu   arr[]={ 17,14,14,12,11,11,9,5,4,2} diff[]={ 12,9,9,7,6,6,4,0,1,3} sorted arr[]={,5 ,4 ,2 ,9 ,11......}

Comment: Put that in your question. It doesn't really adequately explain what you are trying to do. But it does help and I think I I understand it now. The problem in your code is that you aren't actually sorting the `diff` array. You are only comparing the values in `diff` but you need to actually do the swaps for `diff` as well.

Comment: @AlanAu yes comparing diff values but at same index swaping arr vaues

Comment: Liek I said, that doesn't work. You need to sort both at the same time. Otherwise your comparisions are not correct. You are doing insertion sort which relies on the values being updated each iteration. You are not updating the `diff` array so all the comparisions apart from the first outer loop iteration are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

based on the example you provided:-

```
arr[]={ 17,14,14,12,11,11,9,5,4,2}
diff[]={ 12,9,9,7,6,6,4,0,1,3} 
sorted arr[]={,5 ,4 ,2 ,9 ,11......}
```

> **Algorithm:-**
>
> use can use *selection sort* with some modification.
>   1. find index of 1st minimum in diff[].
>   ---(diff[7]=0 therefore index=7)
>   2.swap arr[] with arr[i] and arr[index_of_minimum]. (initially i=0)
>   ---(swap arr[0] & arr[7]) so, new arr[]={5,14,14,12,11,11,9,17,4,2}
>   3.1st element is sorted so i++.
>   4.find index of 2nd minimum in diff[] and repeat till size of diff[].